# Apache camel quartz2 cron scheduler is not working

Tags: apache, apache-camel

I am trying to implement the quartz scheduler and it is not working.
The files are getting moved from the drop off location immediately.

I wanted the job to be triggered every 3 minutes. Am I missing some thing?. I really appreciate your help here.

below is the code I am trying to use

```
<bean id="startPolicy" class="org.apache.camel.routepolicy.quartz.CronScheduledRoutePolicy">
<property name="routeStartTime" value="*/3 * * * * ?"/>
</bean> 

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route id="testRoute" routePolicyRef="startPolicy" autoStartup="false">
    <from uri="file:C:/filedropOffLocation?idempotent=true&delete=true"/>
    <to uri="file:C:/tempFileLocation"/>
</route>
</camelContext>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use route policy. File component itself supports scheduling. Below is the sample code working well in my system,

```
<route id="File_Poller">    
    <from uri="file:{{project_root}}/{{drop_zone}}?scheduler=quartz2&amp;scheduler.cron=0+0/3+*+1/1+*+?+*"/>
    <to uri="direct:xxxx"/> 
</route>
```

The above cron expression run every 3 minutes.  Hope it helps !!